# Can the signers of a 2 of 3 multisig tx be identified later

Tags: multi-signature

For accountability reasons:

If public keys of each signer is known, can the 2 out of 3 parties be identified later, or just that it was some combination of the 3 parties?

If the 2 parties can not be identified, how should this be done if its necessary?

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean transactions with more than one signature attached to them, *not* transactions with a single signature made by multiple parties (threshold signatures). Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When spending a multisig output, the signatures and redeem script are public information.

This allows you to identify:

1. The number of potential signers
2. The number of required signatures
3. Public keys for all potential signers
4. Which keys signed the transaction (from the signature).

It will not reveal the identity of who owns a public key, unless you have some offchain analysis to go with this data, and already know who owns which public key.